# C# LINQ groupby(), grouping by repeated values

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, group-by

I am using Entity Framework and LINQ.
I have a list called "DatosCalc" values ​​are obtained from a filtered by date and identifier input and ordered by date base.
The following code:

```
    List<Registro> datosCalcA = new List<Registro>(); 
    MonitoreoEntities _context = new MonitoreoEntities();

   datosCalcA= _context.Registroes.Where(a => a.PuntoDeMedicionId == pPuntoDeMedicionId
                      && a.EntradaSalidaId == _operadorA
                      || a.EntradaSalidaId == _operadorB
                      && a.FechaHoraRegistro <= _fechaHoraFinal
                      && a.FechaHoraRegistro >= _fechaHoraInicial).OrderBy(i => i.FechaHoraRegistro).ToList();
```

I get this:

```
FechaHoraRegistro 12/05/2014 1:52:07 PM} {System.DateTime
ID 1 decimal
Decimal value 29

FechaHoraRegistro 12/05/2014 1:52:07 PM} {System.DateTime
ID 2 decimal
Decimal value 24

FechaHoraRegistro 12/05/2014 2:03:14 PM} {System.DateTime
ID 1 decimal
Decimal value 24

FechaHoraRegistro 12/05/2014 2:03:14 PM} {System.DateTime
ID 2 decimal
Decimal value 25
.............
+ Raw View
+ DatosCalcA Count = 2767 System.Collections.Generic.List <SystemaControl.Registro>
```

To group by date, I create a new list using GroupBy ()

```
newList var = datosCalcA.GroupBy (i => i.FechaHoraRegistro) .ToList ();
```

In this case brings me the dates correctly, newList I have dates, but not the values ​​and need. And what I get is a list grouped by date

```
FechaHoraRegistro 12/05/2014 1:52:07 PM} {System.DateTime
Decimal value 29
Decimal value 24

FechaHoraRegistro 12/05/2014 2:03:14 PM} {System.DateTime
Decimal value 24
Decimal value 25
```

excuse my English

**And this solved the problem, I'm looking bad breakpoint, it works correctly.
Thank You**

Comment: Are you sure you don't have the values?  What do you get when you do `var.Select (s => s.First ())`?  Don't you see the first values of all the different groupings?  In order to see the keys, you would have to write `var.Select (s => s.Key)`.

Comment: And this solved the problem, I'm looking bad breakpoint, it works correctly.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

you need to add `.Select()` to your data

```
var newData =  datosCalcA.GroupBy (i => i.FechaHoraRegistro).Select (x => new {  values =  x.Sum(y => y.value)}).ToList ();
```